# Eventloop is not updating the GUI widget opacity value

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

I have a button widget I'd like to fade out (`self.button1`)

```
def button_slot(self):
    fade_effect = QtGui.QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
    self.button1.setGraphicsEffect(fade_effect)
    hideAnimation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(fade_effect, "opacity")
    hideAnimation.setDuration(5000)
    hideAnimation.setStartValue(1.0)
    hideAnimation.setEndValue(0.0)
    hideAnimation.start(QtCore.QPropertyAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
    self.hideAnimation = hideAnimation
```

The code is in PyQt, but is the same as the original Qt.

For a reason, the when I try the code separately in a test file, it works well.
However, when trying to integrate it in my code, it seems like the fading out animation is running in the background, but not updated in the GUI itself:

- The button is stuck at the "clicked" state.
- If I minimize and enlarge the window, The button's opacity is right where it's supposed to be (for example, if the duration is 5000ms from 1.0 to 0.0, enlarging the window after 2500ms will show 0.5 opacity).
- The button is clickable even though it looks "stuck".

Why could this be happening? How can I force the GUI to update itself at every event iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible explanation I have is that you're blocking the event loop somewhere else in your code. The animation will definitely run, as your test case shows, but it's invoked from the event loop. If your code blocks -- if there's any place in your code where you wait for things, sleep, etc., then that's your problem.

GUI code in Qt and many other frameworks must be written in run-to-completion fashion. Every slot and event handler must execute as quickly as it can, and then return. When you add a breakpoint in a slot, and look at the stack trace when the code stops, you'll see that `QEventLoop::exec()` is somewhere there. Ultimately, all GUI code is called from the event loop.

Try reducing your code piecewise until the problem vanishes. That's how you'll know where the blocking part is. Qt provides, unfortunately, many methods named `waitxxx()`, and they tend to be used without understanding that they block the event loop. A blocked event loop means that the application does not respond to user interaction, and eventually the OS will detect it and issue a spinning beachball (OS X), a spinning circle (Vista/Win7) or perhaps a message about a stuck application. A spinning beachball/circle means that the application's main event loop is blocked.

Comment: This is not the case here. The eventloop is not blocked, as any other `QRect` animations works fine. I can continue using the main GUI window. And the widgets gets resampled only when it's hidden. I recorded this behaviour into an AVI file: http://itayb.hostzi.com/eventloop_doesnt_update.avi

Comment: Set up a 40ms timer and connect its `timeout()` signal to the `update()` slot on that opacity-animated widget. If that helps, it'd make it a Qt bug, or perhaps more likely a PyQt bug.

Comment: That didn't help. I tried removing parts of the code, and succeeded in fiding the problematic object. for some reason, if a  QAxContainer.QAxWidget widget is displayed, it breaks the fading effect. This behavior is familiar?

Comment: OK, that's getting *somewhere*. Are you displaying it as a child of the same widget where the problem button is a child, or is it a separate window? Try making the container a separate window and see if it helps. I still claim it's a Qt/PyQt bug at this point, as I said before, unless you're somehow using the ActiveX container incorrectly.

Comment: I'm getting the problem only if it's in the same window. If it's running on a seperated window - it works fine. hwo can I make a container for a seperate window and inject it in the main window?

Comment: You can't, or rather, you can only by redirecting painting to a different widget, but I have never tried it and thus would consider it a bad hack anyway. It's supposed to work. You're doing nothing wrong. Please prepare a minimum test case in Python, I'd like to reproduce in C++ and submit as a Qt bug.

Comment: here is a test case in python: http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt%40riverbankcomputing.com/msg25971/animation_test_case.py . You'll have to rewrite it in C++ as I'm not fimiliar with the language.

Comment: Sure! I'll accept the answer, but please update me with any progress on the subject.